# Why does sklearn KMeans changes my dataset after fitting?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am using the KMeans from sklearn to cluster the [College.csv](https://www.science.smith.edu/%7Ejcrouser/SDS136/labs/lab5/College.csv). But when I fit the KMeans model, my dataset changes after that! Before using KMeans, I Standardize the numerical variables with `StandardScaler` and I use `OneHotEncoder` to dummy the categorical variable `"Private"`.

My code is:

```
num_vars = data.columns[1:]
scaler = StandardScaler()
data[num_vars] = scaler.fit_transform(data[num_vars])

ohe = OneHotEncoder()
data["Private"] = ohe.fit_transform(data.Private.values.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()

km = KMeans(n_cluster = 6)
km.fit(data)
```

The dataset before using the KMeans:
[image]

The dataset after using the KMeans:
[image]

Comment: can you show a sample of your dataset before and after? `KMeans` shouldn't modify your dataset. are you applying any transformations to the data before running KMeans such as standardizing the different features?

Comment: @DerekO Yes. I edited my question with more explanation. I will add the images of the dataset before and after KMeans soon.

Comment: can you also include more of your code (such as the standardization and one hot encoding)? to best help you, we should be able to [reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the issue you're having – thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a subtle bug in the posted code. Let's demonstrate it:

```py
new_df = pd.DataFrame({"Private": ["Yes", "Yes", "No"]})
```

`OneHotEncoder` returns something like this:

```py
new_data = np.array(
    [[0, 1],
     [0, 1],
     [1, 0]])
```

What happens if we assign `new_df["Private"]` with our new `(3, 2)` array?

```py
>>> new_df["Private"] = new_data
>>> print(new_df)
   Private
0        0
1        0
2        1
```

Wait, where'd the other column go?

Uh oh, it's still in there ...

... but it's invisible until we look at the actual values:

```py
>>> print(new_df.values)
[[0 1]
 [0 1]
 [1 0]]
```

As @Derek hinted in his answer, KMeans has to validate the data, which usually converts from pandas dataframes into the underlying arrays. When this happens, all your "columns" get shifted to the right by one because there was an invisible column created by the `OneHotEncoder`.

---

Is there a better way?

Yep, use a pipeline!

```py
pipe = make_pipeline(
    ColumnTransformer(
        transformers=[
            ("ohe", OrdinalEncoder(categories=[["No", "Yes"]]), ["Private"]),
        ],
        remainder=StandardScaler(),
    ),
    KMeans(n_clusters=6),
)

out = pipe.fit(df)
```

Comment: oh I see – I didn't realize that print statements wouldn't show 2d arrays within a dataframe. thanks for taking the time to write up this answer!

Answer (score 3):

It appears that when you run `km.fit(data)`, the `.fit` method modifies `data` inplace by inserting a column that is the opposite of your one-hot encoded column. And also confusing is the fact that the `"Terminal"` column disappears.

[image]

For now, you can use this workaround that copies your data:

```
data1 = data.copy()
km = KMeans(n_clusters = 6, n_init = 'auto')
km.fit(data1)
```

Edit: When you run `km.fit`, the first method that is run is `km._validate_data` – which is a validation step that modifies the dataframe that you pass (see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/98cf537f5/sklearn/cluster/_kmeans.py#L1417-L1424) and [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2e481f114169396660f0051eee1bcf6bcddfd556/sklearn/base.py#L534-L536))

For example, if I add the following to the end of your code:

```
km._validate_data(
    data,
    accept_sparse="csr",
    dtype=[np.float64, np.float32],
    order="C",
    accept_large_sparse=False,
)
```

Running this changes your data, but I don't know exactly why this is happening. It may have to do with something about the data itself.

Comment: Yes this is strange. Thanks for your answer and guidance.

Comment: @Sara glad to have helped – it is strange and i've never encountered this issue before. i have a feeling it has to do with something about your data. it might be worth filing an issue and see what the `sklearn` team has to say – i am genuinely curious about the root cause

Comment: @DerekO You were 99% there, I added an answer explaining the rest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75013047/12439119

Answer (score 0):

The data is the same but shifted over by one column. The Apps column never existed before and everything is shifted to the right.
It has something to do with your line
data[num_vars] = scaler.fit_transform(data[num_vars])
which is actually doing a nested double array data[data[columns[1:]].

Basically, you can follow a method like this

> from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

> sc = StandardScaler()

> data[:, 1:] = sc.fit_transform(data[:, 1:])

Comment: I tried this method but the problem isn't solved yet.

Comment: i don't think this is exactly what is happening – if you use print statements to examine the data, it is only after kmeans is applied that the original dataframe changes. also from the sample dataframes that are included, it looks like the columns shift over by 1, this isn't what happens for the entire dataframe.